# Parsley minlength message not getting customized when passing it as option while binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I am using following script to bind the parsley to an input field. I am not able to override the minlength message here to show the custom one. It is showing me the parsley's default error message instead. Am i missing anything ? What could be wrong in it.

```
 $("#first-name").parsley({
        trigger: null,
        required: true,
        minlength:2,
        pattern: "/^[A-Za-z'-]*$/",
        errorsContainer: ".firstNameErrorMessage",
        requiredMessage: "This field is required",
        patternMessage:  "Only letter, apostrophes and dashes allowed",
        minlengthMessage: "Min 2 chars required"
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out the cause of this issue. There was minlength attribute given in markup, I removed that and now i am able to see the custom message. Even, it is now taking care to show one message at a time according to priority.

Need to take care to avoid using any html type attribute or attribute which is same as parsley's built in validator types in the markup (for ex: type="email", type="number" and minlength/maxlength), while binding the parsley using javascript syntax in the question and aiming to bind parsley after document ready with custom messages. 
Otherwise, parsley will bind while dom rendering itself and once bind we cannot override the error message using the syntax in the question to have custom error message as we desire.